# Measuring time taken for 'vagrant up'

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

Is there any way to measure the time taken between executing `vagrant up` to actually being able to `vagrant ssh` into the machine? We use a shared ubuntu dev environment that takes a long time to spin up and I was considering switching the `apt-get install` commands to `apt-fast install` but unless there is a significant improvement I wouldn't be so inclined.

Comment: do you want to measure the time that it takes for your provisioning script to complete? (that's what I guess you mean because you are talking about apt-get) or the total time?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. You're right, I mean the provisioning script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepend your `vagrant up` with `time`.

`$ time vagrant up`

Just before the script finishes you will see output like this:

```
real    0m17.844s
user    0m2.251s
sys 0m0.643s
```

If you want to exclude time for importing the box, setting up network interfaces, port forwards, shared folders mounting etc then measure only time that is needed for provisioning:

1. Bring the box up (without provisioning)

   `$ time vagrant up --no-provision`
2. Measure provisioning time

   `$ time vagrant provision`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following to measure time for my scripts, should work in your provisioning script

```
START=$SECONDS
...
TOTAL=$(($SECONDS - $START))
```

Answer (score 1):

We use chef and that gives us time outputs. Our most effective time saving was building base boxes with the majority of the pre-requisites installed so we aren't downloading and installing apache per-se but just tweaking the configuration. The base box build became it's own vagrant project so it is also source controlled and repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN{
  START_TIME = Time.new
  puts "Start Time : #{START_TIME}"
}
END{
  END_TIME = Time.new
  interval = END_TIME - START_TIME
  puts "  Started at #{START_TIME} and ended at #{END_TIME}."
  puts "  Total time taken:  #{interval}."
  puts "  Completed successfully!"
}
```

This worked for me. Just add this at the beginning of the vagrant file.